# Find words that appear in multiple strings

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that does the following:

- Takes in a list of 10 strings containing 1000 or more words each (including punctuation etc).
- returns a dictionary with the following values:
  1. Words that appear in all 10 strings
  2. Words that appear in 9 strings
  3. Words that appear in 8 strings
    ...
    Words that appear in 2 strings
- Achieves the above in a reasonable time complexity

For example:

```
def findCommonWords(listOfStrings):
   # Do something to get the common words
   answerToReturn = {
"In all 10": "Word1",
"In 9": "Word2",
"In 8": "Word3",
"In 7": "Word4",
"In 6": "Word5",
"In 5": "Word6",
"In 4": "Word7",
"In 3": "Word8",
"In 2": "Word9",
}
   return answerToReturn

listOfStrings = ["word1", "word1 word2", "word1 word2 word3", "word1 word2 word3 word4", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9", "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10" ]
results = findCommonWords(listOfStrings)
```

How could I achieve this reasonably efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this runs O(M*N) //# of string * # of words

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter([w for l in listOfStrings for w in set(l.split())]))
```

Comment: Could you modify this so that it only counts the number of strings that a word appears in instead of the total count, please?

Comment: @themrdan I added a set conversion for that. This does not factor in the punctuations, to do so need to provide a suitable example